# Problem with fetching from external source

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch data in order to tokenize my Credit Card but i have to go with this adress :

`this.state.data.CardRegistrationURL ==  "https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken"`

This is my fetch :

```
 postInfoCard = () => {
    const headers = new Headers({
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    });
    const data = {
      accessKeyRef: this.state.data.AccessKey,
      data: this.state.data.PreregistrationData,
      cardNumber: this.state.cardNumber,
      cardExpirationDate: this.state.cardExpirationDate,
      cardCvx: this.state.cardCvx,
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };

    fetch(this.state.data.CardRegistrationURL, options)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
       console.log(data)
      });
  };
```

but i have several error who are saying
" Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

"Blocking of a cross-origin request: the “Same Origin” policy does not allow consulting the remote resource located at https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken. Reason: The CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is missing"

"Blocking of a Cross-Origin Request: the "Same Origin" policy does not allow viewing of the remote resource located at https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken. Reason: CORS request failed."

Thx for you'r help see you down bellow in comment !

Comment: The "Uncaught (in promise) ..." is seen because you don't have a `.catch()` attached to the `fetch`. The CORS issue is a different, you may have to set `mode: 'cors'` in your options.

Comment: It change nothing at the problem unfortunately

Comment: it's the end point/server that needs to provide `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header ... not your code.

Comment: did you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can actually do about it. This is because the cors headers [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`] are required to be present in the *response*. So the server needs to attach those headers not your code. You can't just give yourself the permission to access a server. It's the server that decides whether to allow your origin or not.

According to [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#functional_overview) on MDN:

> The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing standard works by adding new HTTP headers that let servers describe which origins are permitted to read that information from a web browser.

Note how it mentions "... *headers that let servers describe which origins are permitted* ..."

The best you can do is to proxy the URL through *your own server*. Create an endpoint on your own server that proxies your data to the other cross-origin server and returns the response to your frontend as-is.